# Specify a Grid within a template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

All I want is to add a Kendo UI Grid to the template of a Kendo UI ListView. Every item of the list contains another list which should be shown as a grid inside of the template. Ideally, the grid would be defined with Razor, but I have no idea how to bind the data from the template to the Razor grid. I would be fine with a JavaScript defined grid as well. So here is the current approach.

That's the code to generate the grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildGrid(id, lines) {
        console.log("buildGrid(" + id + ")");
        console.log("lines", lines);
        var grid = $("#" + id).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: lines,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Name: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            columns: [
                "Name"
            ]
        });
        console.log(grid);
    }
</script>
```

That's the code of the template of the ListView:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="recordTemplate">
    <div class="k-widget" style="margin:10px auto 10px auto;">
            # var gridId = "RecordLines" + Line; #
            <div id="#=gridId#" style="border:red 1px solid; width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
            # buildGrid(gridId, Lines); #
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</script>
```

That's the code of the TabStrip with the ListView inside.

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Animation(false)
        .Name("tabs")
        .Items(i => {
            i.Add().Text("Records").Selected(true).Content(@<text>
                <div class="tabDiv">
                    <div class="demo-section">
                        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-add-button" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Zeile hinzufügen</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="demo-section k-header">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ListView<TemplateGeneratorItem.Record>(Model.Records)
                            .Name("RecordsList")
                            .ClientTemplateId("recordTemplate")
                            .DataSource(d => d
                                .Custom()
                                .AutoSync(true)
                                .Events(e => e.Change("changeRecList"))
                                .Schema(s => s.Model(m => m.Id(o => o.Line)))
                                .Sort(s => s.Add(o => o.Line))
                            )
                            .Events(e => e.Remove("removeRecord"))
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border:none;" })
                            .TagName("div")
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
            </text>);
        })
    )
</div>
```

The problem is: The grid does not show up! The output on the JavaScript console looks great (lines contains the expected elements):

```
buildGrid(RecordLines1)
lines [ht.e…d.init, ht.e…d.init, ht.e…d.init, _events: Object]
[context: document, selector: "#RecordLines1"]
```

If I select one of those grids in the console afterwards, I get the `<div>` element and not the grid:

```
$("#RecordLines1");
[<div id=?"RecordLines1" style=?"border:?red 1px solid;? width:?500px;? height:?500px;?">?</div>?]
$("#RecordLines1").data("kendoGrid");
undefined
```

First of all: How do I get my grid in the template?
Bonus: How can I achieve this with Razor?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define grid in template script using MVVM style

```
<div id="gridLines#=Id#" data-role="grid"
     date-scrollable="true"
     data-editable="true"
     data-columns="[ { 'field': 'Name', 'width': 270 }]"
     data-bind="source: Lines,
                events: {
                  save: onSave
                }"
     style="width: 480px; height: 200px"></div>
```

Or with razor,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<LineViewModel>()
      .Name("gridLines#=Id#")
      .Columns(columns =>
               {
                   columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Name");
               })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .PageSize(5)
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("readbyrecord", "line", new { recordId = "#= Id #" }))
      )
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .ToClientTemplate())
```

**Note**: Using razor you need to add extra action controller to read lines by its record id

Comment: I do not see a grid with the first approach. Your `<div>` should replace my `<div id="#=gridId#"...`, right? Also, there are no error messages.

The option with Razor has one problem: I have all the data in my model. I can't and don't want to load them via Ajax.

Comment: Another approach I've tried:
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    # var gridId = "RecordLines" + Line; #
    # $("\\#" + gridId).kendoGrid({ events: { dataBinding: doIt }, dataSource: { data: Lines, schema: { model: { fields: { Name: { type: "string" } } } } }, columns: [ "Name" ] }); #
    # console.log("records grid", $("\\#" + gridId)); #

But as written before, the output of "records grid" is the simple input element. Which by the way is attached to the document: nodeName="#document", parentNode and parentElement are null...

Comment: My bad for mvvm, code updated. Unfortunately until now I don't find a way to assign javascript data to grid through razor, the only option you have with MVVM.. If i got some time I would edit the answer with following sample..

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or dojo with your current approach? Reading your code through comment is such a pain, and wont solve anything.. A fiddle or dojo will be more helpful though

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I've tried to avoid to load the data via Ajax for many hours but it seems inevitable. So I took your suggest solution with Razor.